# Get a notification in Swing when a thread completes / is finished

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

It seems I miss a certain point in Java and Swing. The issue is as follows:

- I have a swing GUI with a Start / Stop button (And some more)
- It starts the function (What is set up as a thread in this case), Thread starts, it works, Swing GUI is fully operational and does all the other things it is made for, e.g. modifying parameters for the worker thread.
- Of course, sending an interrupt to ask the thread to stop on users request is in and functions. So far so good.

But I did not found a way that Swing GUI notices the thread stopped on its own:
If I ignore it, it confuses the user.
I of course put a loop in, where Swing GUI regularly asks if Thread.isAlive (And sleeps some time to ask again), but this loop completely blocks Swing GUI.
Ideally, I would like to get a notification or an event that the thread has stopped.
Just like all the other events, Swing processes:-) .

What is the proper way to set it up?

Comment: check more comments on this thread [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9672081/java-threading-swing-app][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9672081/java-threading-swing-app

Comment: You could establish a observer pattern, where you pass a interface to the thread that it can use to notify the interested party when it's done. But you become responsible for managing the resync to the EDT

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html). It is designed to perform tasks on the background as the result of a Swing event such a button press. It has hooks to listen for when the task finishes.

Comment: Thanks all for the SwingWorker hints!
It's implemented and runs well, including publish and done routine - and I have the gut feeling, my current Java book needs some other 1000 pages :-). 
However, I found on OracleTutorial the class that is aimed to the background task is an inner class of the class that extends „Jframe“. From my undestanding, it is a „must“. Did I get this point right?  I would prefer to have the class that extends  SwingWorker by e.g. by doInBackground(), process(...) and done() completely outside and in a diffferent file.
Is there some reasonable way I just not see?

Comment: It does not need to extend JFrame. The swing worker can be its own class. Just create an object that extends SwingWorker.

Answer (score 0):

use a boolean flag 'done' private field. initialize done=false; when your thread run() method is complete set done=true inside thread run() method.
monitoring the value of the flag 'done' will tell you when your thread has finished.

Comment: I did it, monitoring the flag by using a timer + timer event, checking each 100 ms. It fulfilled most of my req'ments. But not sure - What is the more Swing appropriate style for this? Bounds? Progress Indicator?

Comment: you can use swing progressMonitor for visual thread progress. or simply changing your Cursor type to wait indicating to user some background task is running